# Add a column to a table and then "insert into" is invalid in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem similar to this [SO question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/80943/7820).

I have three tables that are related with an identity column as primary key. And I need to clone them into a new database with new identity values.

These are the tables where I'm going to copy the data, but the relationship is the same in the source database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [CodeId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Serial]            NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [...]
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aggregation] (
    [AggregationId] INT           NOT NULL,
    [Created]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Aggregation_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregationChildren] (
    [AggregationChildrenId] INT NOT NULL,
    [AggregationId]         INT NOT NULL,
    [Position]              INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationChildrenId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationChildrenId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Aggregation]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Aggregation] ([AggregationId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

There is a master table, Code, and the other tables related to the master by its primary key `Code.CodeId`.

I'm going to add an auxiliary column, with the value of the primary key in the source database, to make the conversion in tables `Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren`.

That process work in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I try to use it in a procedure stored it complains about that the auxiliary column doesn't exist.

The stored procedure is like this pseudo code:

```
// Alter table to add the auxiliary column
// Insert into with select and inserting into the auxiliary column
// Alter table to drop the auxiliary column
```

The stored procedure has an error because I'm inserting in a column that doesn't exist.

Do you know if there is another solution to this problem using an auxiliary column?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a column and use it **in the same batch**; in Management Studio you are able to insert "go" between them so it works, in stored procedure you can insert your table within EXEC like this:

```
exec('insert table..(old_cols, new_col)...')
```

The table structure is checked if a table exists so the procedure cannot be compiled when you use a new column, but it will not check a dynamic code that compiles on its own and when it will be compiled the column will be already there

Comment: You'll actually need the insert to be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, of course, Aaron is right, I'll update the post, thank you!